# linking a static library in ios

Tags: ios, xcode4, static-linking

I have created a math based application in Xcode 4.4. I am using tabbar based app with the help of storyboard.

I have written all my math functions in a separate class called  `CalculationMethods` which is the subclass of NSObject.

My ViewController:

```
//  FirstViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CalculationMethods.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@end

//  FirstViewController.m

#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "CalculationMethods.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%f",[self julianDateFinder: [self currentDayMonthAndYearFinder]]);
}

@end
```

As you can see I have included my CalculationMethod.h file in both FirstViewController.h and the FirstViewController.m file, but when I use the methods of that class such as `julianDateFinder` and `currentDayMonthAndYearFinder`, Xcode errors, saying:

> "No Visible @interface for 'FirstViewController' declares the selector 'CurrentDayMonthAndYearFinder'"

I am new to iOS and XCode. Can anyone help me solve the error?

Comment: what does your CalculationMethods.h file look like?

Comment: I also don't think you mean static library in the objective C sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the FirstViewController, to use any of the methods in the CalculationMethods class, you need to create an instance of CalculationMethods.  And then access a method using this syntax:  `[instanceOfCalculationMethods aMethodInCalculationMethods];`

For example in your case, try this:

In the FirstViewController.h file, before the @end:

```
CalculationMethods *_calculationMethods;
```

And in the viewDidLoad method:

```
_calculationMethods = [CalculationMethods alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%f",[_calculationMethods julianDateFinder: [_calculationMethods currentDayMonthAndYearFinder]]);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! for your help, i am actually C developer and totally new to iOS development, infect  this is my first app that i am developing,  so i forget that i have created a new class  & to use a class first i have to make instance of it

Comment: You can also write pure C style functions and have them declared in the .h file and implemented in the .m file.  So you can use those functions without having a pointer to an instance of Obj-C class.  But it would be another SO question...:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding how Objective C works slightly.

Without adding details of the `CalculationMethods.h` header file I can't help you much, but that compiler warning is telling you that `FirstViewController` doesn't have the method `currentDayMonthAndYearFinder`.

The reason that this is the case is because you're calling performing the selector `CurrentDayMonthAndYearFinder`  on `self` which in the context of your `FirstViewController` instance is in fact the instance of `FirstViewController`

You said it yourself that your method `CurrentDayMonthAndYearFinder` is on your `CalculatorMethods` class so I suggest you either create an instance of your CalculatorMethods class or call the class method named `CurrentDayMonthAndYearFinder` on your CalculatorMethods class.

The problem here is weather or not you've defined instance methods or class methods.

Do *yourself* a favour and update your question with the contents of `CalculationMethods.h`

Comment: It is there i have implemented it